# Adding a character after the first element of a list

Tags: css, wordpress, pseudo-element

I have a wordpress list with just two elements and I would like to add a simple character, like "-" after the first element of such list.
Is it possible to do it with pseudo-elements in css?

What I'd need to tell my css would be to add something :after the :first-child of my list.

Is this at all possible?

Thanks in advance!

Alex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible in CSS:

```
li:first-child::after {
  content: "-"
}
```